# Which Pom is parent?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

In a maven project which pom.xml is the parent pom? And is that the one I need to change in order to add a profile?

I have a simple project and am trying to add a profile to download from a specific repository but nothing's seems to be working.

Comment: Please post your non working pom.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a multi-module build.

Parent relationship is optional between poms, and specified with the `<parent>` tag inside the pom.

You may point to a single pom, but if not, you point to a default super-pom.

Use `mvn help:effective-pom` to shed some light on your settings.

If you have a shared pom file, you can add profiles to that one, otherwise you need to include them in each pom.

Use `mvn help:active-profiles` to see which ones are enabled.

For ref: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html